# Can I return header before stream have not perpared?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download, asp.net-core-webapi

I noticed that `FileStreamResult` will call `Stream.ReadAsync` looply and push datas to network stream until it returns 0.
But the http response header will be send to client after first time to call `Stream.ReadAsync` when completed.
Now I need return a stream which generated by a long time process. I need return header before the stream have not generated.
Is it possible?

What's I tried:
First call `ReadAsync` returns 0 will stop `FileStreamResult` reading stream and dispose it.
Returns 1 will sent a zero byte into network stream and break the data.

That is I have to return some of data from the stream on the first call to `ReadAsync`, even a byte, to tell service the stream can be read now, and it's time to sent header to tell client this.
But the stream hasn't been generated yet and it's impossible for me to return any reliable data.
I can't return 0, it ends the connection.

Comment: What is the time scale of the process? Maybe you can just return `http accepted` until you have actual results?

Comment: I can confirm that I see the same issue re the header not being sent before the first call to `Read`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually not sure if there's a better solution to this, but I've managed to solve the issue by making a custom `IActionResultExecutor<FileStreamResult>`, based off the default one used in ASP.NET Core:

```
public class CustomFileStreamResultExecutor : FileStreamResultExecutor
{
    public CustomFileStreamResultExecutor(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task WriteFileAsync(
        ActionContext context, 
        FileStreamResult result, 
        RangeItemHeaderValue? range,
        long rangeLength)
    {
        // Ensure everything we have so far has been sent
        await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();

        // Continue with the normal functionality from here on out
        await base.WriteFileAsync(context, result, range, rangeLength);
    }
}
```

And then we can register it before we call `services.AddControllers();` (if you register it afterwards, ASP.NET Core will already have registered its own):

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IActionResultExecutor<FileStreamResult>, CustomFileStreamResultExecutor>();
```

You can find the code for the default executor [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6d21cf11d65283fadbeb044b760c2f4dcf2c7010/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs).